# Probability regarding distribution of fruits in pudding

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> The number of fruits in a pudding follows a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda =60$. A person grabs all fruits from the pudding and shares them with a friend with the following procedure.
> He tosses a balanced coin and gives a fruit to his friend if the result is heads, and gives the fruit to himself if the result is tails.
> i) Find the distribution of the number of fruits the friend gets.
> ii) Find the probability that each of them gets $30$ fruits.
> iii) Find the probability that the pudding has more than $60$ fruits, given that the friend got $30$ fruits.

My attempt:
If $X$ is the random variable counting the number of fruits in the pudding, we have $X\sim \operatorname{Po}(60)$. If $Y$ is the random variable counting the number of fruits the friend gets, since the event of getting a fruit has probability $\frac{1}{2}$ (because the coin is balanced) we get $Y\sim \operatorname{Po}(30)$. This answers i).
If $Z$ is the random variable counting the number of fruits he gets, with the same reasoning we find $Z\sim \operatorname{Po}(30)$. Now, I think that $Y$ and $Z$ are independent (I'm not really sure), so $\mathbb{P}(Y=30,Z=30)=\mathbb{P}(Y=30)\cdot \mathbb{P}(Z=30)=\frac{30^{30}}{30!}e^{-30}\cdot \frac{30^{30}}{30!}e^{-30}$. So this should answer ii).
I have no idea about iii).

Is this correct? How can I complete the proof?